# NuGet Pack: Ignore packages.config for dependencies and use .nuspec file instead

Tags: dependencies, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec, packages.config

In my .nuspec file i list my dependencies as such

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="Some.Package" version="[1.0,2.0)" />
  ...
</dependencies>
```

However, when i pack my project, i get this message:

> Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies

I don't want this, i want to use my listed dependencies in the .nuspec file.

I realise that there is a setting **developmentDependency** can be used to ignore a package. But since this is potentially a lot of packages, it would make more sense to use the .nuspec file instead of packages.config

I am using NuGet.exe version 2.8 to pack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to pack your *.csproj* file. By doing this, NuGet is not looking at your *.nuspec* file. That is why you are getting the message.

> Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies

Using the project file is just a shortcut. If you want to be more explicit about how you want your package created, including dependencies and what files to include, you will need to specify the *.nuspec* file in nuget pack.

```
nuget pack Your.Library.nuspec
```